# Gradle; How to start/stop JBoss AS 7.1.1

Tags: gradle, jboss7.x

I am new to Gradle and started learning the same. I am able to deploy the web application into jboss through Gradle. I need to stop and start the server after the deployment. Please let me know how to invoke the script from Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom exec task to start and stop jboss. You can then either define dependsOn accordingly or call them in order when you invoke gradle.

```
task startJboss(type:Exec) {
    workingDir = "" //set the working dir
    commandLine = "" //set the command to execute to start jboss.
}
```

There are also a few gradle jboss plugins you can look at:

- https://github.com/ylemoigne/gradle-jboss-controller
- https://github.com/mamohr/jboss-deployment-structure
- https://github.com/zhurlik/gradle-jboss-modules-plugin